# Where to put spring configuration files when using maven

Tags: spring, unit-testing, maven, junit

I'm trying to solve my configuration-files-problem.

I have Spring MVC application with this structure (my current structure)

```
src/main/java/ ....................... (java classes)
src/main/resources/ .................. (some .properties files )
src/main/webapp/ ..................... (web content, web.xml )
src/main/webapp/spring/ .............. (other spring config files, app-confix.xml, etc.)
src/main/webapp/myApp-servlet.xml .... (servlet config)


src/test/java ........................ (java test classes)
src/test/resources ................... (some test .properties files)
```

(that is pretty standard maven project directory structure)

So, and my question is: **Should I put spring configuration files to resources directory or not ?**
I'm not sure if they can be considered as resource files. Most of the spring projects have configuration in WEB-INF/ directory. But there is one problem with unit testing, because when I need to load servlet configuration then is maven expecting configuration files in /test/resources directory. I know, that I can copy context xml file to the tested class and everything will be ok, but that not look so good for me.

I was reading a lot of articles on the internet, but I'm still not sure what is the right way.

So I have tree options:

**1.** stay with current structure

**2.** move all spring configuration to the /main/(java|test)/resources
Here I can see one bad thing. All configuration files will be in classes directory and I'm not sure if this is right.

**3.** move only servlet config to the /main/(java|test)/resources and keep other spring configuration files in /WEB-INF/ directory.

So, what do you recommend ? 
What is the best practices for configuration files placement when using Spring with Maven and JUnit ?

*UPDATE:* fixed directory naming in option 2. and 3.

*UPDATE:* I found very interesting reading [1] about best practices in Spring. It looks very promising and confirming Ralph's solution. I'm still not happy about presence META-INF directory in `WEB-INF/classes` but, well ... nothing is perfect.

[1] http://gordondickens.com/wordpress/2012/07/03/enterprise-spring-best-practices-part-1-project-config/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A common pattern (for example used by Spring Roo applications) is to put the configuration files under `src\main\resources\META-INF\spring\`

Then you can load them via the same expression `classpath:META-INF\spring\application-context.xml` in tests as well as in your application.

Comment: Ok, that is reasonable solution and where I should place context files which are used only for unit/integration tests ? To the `src\test\resources\META-INF\` directory ?

Comment: In an test resource folder: `src\test\resources\...`

Comment: I'm so sorry, but I have another strange issue. I followed your recommendation but my META-INF dir is copied into `WEB-INF/classes` directory. So, in my case I have all configuration files in `webApp/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring...`. I'm not sure if this is the right behavior, i think all files in `java/main/resources/META-INF` should be in the `webApp/META-INF` directory and not in the `webApp/WEB-INF/classes` directory.

Comment: that is completely fine, your webapp/META-INF holds the MANIFEST.MF file and maven information only and that is OK.

Comment: Yap, `webapp/META-INF` is correct path, but after project build I found my META-INF (with spring config) directory in `webapp/WEB-INF/classes/`. I found why, because everything what is `/java/main/resources/` is copied into the `WEB-INF/classes/`. But I'm not sure if this is correct behavior or I have wrong maven configuration (or something else)

Comment: That is the expected behavior. The maven resource folder will be "merged" into the classes folder. Therefore it is accessible via class path.

Comment: Thanks for this -- great answer.  I have been in Spring XML Hell since yesterday with this and other issues, but this is definitely the right approach to be able to reference the configuration files from both the unit tests and the web app.