# spring where to store xml config files

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, configuration-files, directory-structure

I'm developing a spring project and I've just encountered serious problems with loading XML config files within junit (but they are accessible from the web controllers) - can't load XML files.

I listed my classpath (in junit tests) and found that, among the rest, there are 2 directories  included:

```
/var/www/Java/lyricsBase/build/web/WEB-INF/classes/
/var/www/Java/lyricsBase/build/test/classes/
```

There is just one file I want to include in my test:

- /WEB-INF/lyricsBaseApp-servlet.xml

and it imports 3 files below:

- /WEB-INF/hibernate.xml
- /WEB-INF/dataSource.xml
- /WEB-INF/beans.xml

I can clearly see that deploying my project on tomcat copies confg files to `/var/www/Java/lyricsBase/build/web/WEB-INF/ABC.xml` but this directory is not in the classpath, `/var/www/Java/lyricsBase/build/web/WEB-INF/classes` is included instead. I read that WEB-INF should not be in the classpath (it's just a Java EE principle). OK - so where should I put my config files to access them easily both from web controllers and junit tests? Any good practices?

Comment: When you use Maven, than have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13859755/where-to-put-spring-configuration-files-when-using-maven

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the config files under WEB-INF/classes on the war package, and they will be loaded into the classpath. Consider deploying your code as an exploded war, so the config files can be changed easily.

Also consider using maven war project for your packaging. If you do, you can just place your config files under src/main/resources under the source code, and they will be packaged into WEB-INF/classes for you.

Comment: Placing source XML files under WEB-INF/classes seems to be a dirty workaround. Maven seems to be the best solution then.

Comment: Other approach I've seen is to add an additional location to your tomcat classpath and place your config file there (need to dig tomcat manual how to do this)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and from then on started putting them in META-INF under resources. This is where the spring template projects which don't run in Tomcat put them and seemed to solve my issues.

Comment: but I am using Tomcat... and I can't see META-INF in my classpath.